# Кавалерия короля Георга — чемоданы с деньгами?

Tags: фразеология

Есть ли подобный фразеологизм в русском языке? Встретил в тексте цитату американского эксперта по ЦРУ Лока Джонсона:

> «Мы занимались подобным с момента создания ЦРУ в 1947 году, - цитирует
>   «The New York Times» Джонсона. - Мы использовали постеры, памфлеты,
>   растяжки и так далее. Мы распространяли ложную информацию в
>   иностранной прессе. Мы использовали то, что британцы называют
>   кавалерией короля Георга, то есть чемоданы с деньгами».

Однако больше употреблений нет. Возможно, стоило бы ещё и в сообществе английского языка поинтересоваться, да и вообще не нашёл подтверждений в истории подобного факта.

PS Напомнило: [осел, груженный золотом, возьмет неприступную крепость](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BF_II_%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Comment: @М_Г Мне кажется, что одно слово "есть" в заголовке лишнее. Может быть, лучше так: _Кавалерия короля Георга — чемоданы с деньгами?_

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Принято. Спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это растиражированное прессой искажение, допущенное самим Джонсоном или неверно записанное с его слов (*We've used what the British call 'King George's cavalry...*). Не "*король Георг*", а **Святой Георгий**, покровитель Англии. Его образ когда-то чеканился на золотой гинее. *The Golden Cavalry of St George* - образное наименование британских субсидий странам, противостоявшим Наполеону:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Cavalry_of_St_George

Упоминание Вассерманом "*кавалерии Святого Георгия*" в значении твёрдой валюты:
https://history.wikireading.ru/8350

**P.S.** Можно было бы сделать скидку на то, что на монетах в своё время и король Георг изображался, но тогда была бы проблема с "конницей" (святой изображался *на коне*, соотв. "конница" - множество золотых). Возможно, что ходило в конце войны ироничное (со ссылкой на тогдашнего короля) видоизменение устойчивого выражения, и Джонсон его таким запомнил. В современных текстах оно не встречается.